# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

So I created a table name locations:

create table locations (

```
location_id int primary key,

street_address varchar(50),

postal_code varchar(30),

city char(20),

state_province char(30),

country_id char(5)
```

);

and I was supposed to input these data in the table locations:

```
insert into locations values(1000, '1297 Via Cola di Rie', '989', 'Roma', null, 'IT');

insert into locations values(1100, '93091 Calle della Te', '10934', 'Venice', null, 'IT');

insert into locations values(1200, '2017 Shinjuku-ku', '1689', 'Tokyo', 'Tokyo Prefecture', 'JP');

insert into locations values(1300, '9450 Kamiya-cho', '6823', 'Hiroshima', null, 'JP');

insert into locations values(1400, '2014 Jabberwocky Rd', '26192', 'Southlake Texas', 'Texas', 'US');

insert into locations values(1500, '2011 Interiors Blvd', '99236', 'South San', 'California', 'US');

insert into locations values(1600, '2007 Zagora St', '50090', 'South Brun', 'New Jersey', 'US');

insert into locations values(1700, '2004 Charade Rd', '98199', 'Seattle', 'Washington', 'US');

insert into locations values(1800, '147 Spadina Ave', 'MSV 2L7', 'Toronto', 'Ontario', 'CA');

insert into locations values(1900, '6092 Boxwood St', 'YSW 9T2', 'Whitehorse', 'Yukon', 'CA');

insert into locations values(2000, '40-5-12 Laogianggen', '190518', 'Beijing', null, 'CN');

insert into locations values(2100, '1298 Vilaparle (E)', '490231', 'Bombay', 'Maharashtra', 'IN');

insert into locations values(2200, '12-98 Victoria Street', '2901', 'Sydney', 'New South Wale', 'AU');

insert into locations values(2300, '198 Clementi Norrth', '540198', 'Singapore', null, 'SG');

insert into locations values(2400, '8204 Arthur St', null, 'London', null, 'UK');

insert into locations values(2500, 'Magdalen Centre, The OX9 9ZB', 'Oxford', 'Oxford', 'UK');

insert into locations values(2600, '9802 Chester Road', '9629850293', 'Stretford', 'Manchester', 'UK');

insert into locations values(2700, 'Schwanthalerstr. 703', '80925', 'Munich', 'Bavaria', 'DE');

insert into locations values(2800, 'Rua Frei Caneca 1360', '01307-002', 'Sao Paulo', 'Sao Paulo', 'BR');

insert into locations values(2900, '20 Rue des Corps-Sai', '1730', 'Geneva', 'Geneve', 'CH');

insert into locations values(3000, 'Murtenstrasse 921', '3095', 'Bern', 'BE', 'CH');

insert into locations values(3100, 'Pieter Breughlstraa', '3029SK', 'Utrecht', 'Utrecht', 'NL');

insert into locations values(3200, 'Mariano Escobedo 999', '11932', 'Mexico Cit', 'Distrito Feder','MX');
```

Everything was going fine till 1900, but when I tried to execute insert command from the 2000 it gives me this error message "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".
How can I fix this?
Sorry if my question is dumb or obvious, I just started learning databases and mysql

Comment: How many arguments are there in 1900? How many arguments are there in 2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting data into a MySQL table, you will have to specify which data goes into which column. You do this by specifying the column names before the VALUES part like:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('value1','value2');
```

Comment: I see, It seems I cannot escape the formal and more slow way of doing things. Thanks m8!